# How to sort xml tags using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new as member in stack overflow, even if I often use it since a long time.

I'm trying to sort some tags into an xml file using a xslt file.

My file.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nots>
    <base_name>
        <label>B_bn</label>
        <functionality>
            <label>B_f2</label>
            <mails>z_user@domain.com</mails>
            <mails>f_user@domain.com</mails>
            <mails>a_user@domain.com</mails>
        </functionality>
        <functionality>
            <label>A_f1</label>
            <mails></mails>
        </functionality>
        <functionality>
            <label>C_f3</label>
            <mails>x_user@domain.com</mails>
            <mails>a_user@domain.com</mails>
        </functionality>
    </base_name>
    <base_name>
        <label>A_bn</label>
        <functionality>
            <label>C_f3</label>
            <mails></mails>
        </functionality>
        <functionality>
            <label>A_f1</label>
            <mails></mails>
        </functionality>
        <functionality>
            <label>B_f2</label>
            <mails></mails>
        </functionality>
    </base_name>
</nots>
```

I would like to obtain in output a new file.xml in which the tags "base_name", "functionality" and "mails" are sorted.

Using the follow xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="urn:TestNamespace">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="base_name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="label" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="functionality">
                    <xsl:sort select="label" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="nots">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="base_name">
                <xsl:sort select="label" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm able to sort the tags "base_name" and "funzionality", but because I'm new with xslt, I don't know how to sort also the tags mails.

Please, could someone tell me how to resolve it? thanks in advance for your support! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the following template, to sort `mails`, by their child text node.

```
<xsl:template match="functionality">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="label" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mails">
                <xsl:sort select="text()" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or you could do this....

```
<xsl:template match="functionality">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="label" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mails">
                <xsl:sort select="." />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Here `.` represents the current node (i.e. the `mails` node selected for sorting). As your `mails` node only have a single text node, the value of the current node will just be that.